# Need to route HTTP and HTTPS traffic to my server farm

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I have a four-server configuration to achieve load balancing and fault tolerance of three web applications. The scenario is as follow:

- Two servers with IIS-ARR each other with NLB configuration.
- Two servers belonging to a server farm hosting two IIS web-app answering in HTTPS and one only in HTTP.

I configuried ARR-Url rewrite on two balancers as follows:
[image]

Unfortunately balancers are routing fine HTTPS traffic to the farm and when I try to reach the app that responds just in HTTP I got a 404 error on client side.

"HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

The app is properly configured and I guess the problem is on the IIS URL Rewrite which is misconfigured.